# How can I upgrade Python to 2.7.9 on Ubuntu 14.4?

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04

Ubuntu 14.4 comes with Python 2.7.6 built-in, but I'd like to upgrade it to 2.7.9 (it has security features that I want).

Is that even possible?  If so, how can this be achieved?

Comment: The upstream version of python 2.7 is always going to be 2.7.6. Check the distribution version number, and then check the changelog (http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/trusty/python2.7) to see if those security updates have been backported.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use pyenv:

```
 git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git ~/.pyenv
 git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv.git ~/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv
```

Then add

```
   #   for PyEnv
  export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
  export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
  export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/shims:$PATH"
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

to .bash_profile
then you can see the python version you want to install or update:

```
pyenv install --list
```

want python 2.7.18? First you install it:

```
 pyenv install 2.7.18
```

after which you can create a virtualenv using it:

```
 pyenv virtualenv 2.7.18
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: For Ubuntu, that block works better in ~/.bashrc rather than ~/.bash_profile.  Then do exec "$SHELL".

Comment: question was about 2.7.9 you write 2.7.18

Answer (score 31):

[ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes) is the latest version of python2.7

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It will upgrade python to 2.7.10

Comment: tried in development machines (all 14.04 desktops), very good alternative.

Comment: But I found it was not compatible with my app.

Comment: Beware that relying on an unofficial package, and/or a PPA, especially for something as fundamental as Python in Ubuntu, bypasses important security processes & can lead to many problems.  Some packages explicitly depend on the official packages or versions.  Instead, you may well want to use a virtualenv with a more recent version of python for just the apps you need it for.  See also [Upgrade to Python 2.7.9 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and make your own .deb package for deployment - Renoir Boulanger](https://renoirboulanger.com/blog/2015/04/upgrade-python-2-7-9-ubuntu-14-04-lts-making-deb-package/)

Comment: Good. You are right. I gave up my approach several months ago.

Comment: This will upgrade **all** your packages.

Comment: Yes, this solution brings in much of side effect.

Comment: no effect still 2.7.6

Answer (score 14):

I'm not a fan of previous answers suggesting installing from various PPAs. No disrespect intended, but I don't know the people who built them and I have no idea what might be in there. In any environment where someone has to answer to a security professional that practice would be frowned upon.

I just found that downloading 2.7.18 from source and installing it side-by-side was a good start. [This awesome blog post](https://renoirboulanger.com/blog/2015/04/upgrade-python-2-7-9-ubuntu-14-04-lts-making-deb-package/) covered the steps. (recreated here to conform to stack overflow guidelines)

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.18/Python-2.7.18.tgz
tar xfz Python-2.7.18.tgz
cd Python-2.7.18/
./configure --prefix /usr/local/lib/python2.7.18
make
make install
```

Test if the version works

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7.18/bin/python -V
Python 2.7.18
```

Now that I have 2.7.18 installed I can call it directly or symlink to it from wherever I want. (or copy it into a virtualenv etc.)

And note that I got here from a situation where I was getting insecure platform warnings, and SNI Missing warnings. Which led me [here](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings). I imagine many people are finding this question through the same path.
And if that's why you're here this snippet may be of use to you too

```
pip install urllib3[secure]
```

Comment: This is actually the better answer, especially if you are already using `virtualenv`. Reason i feel that this is better, is that it doesn't rely on any third party applications or repositories that may break something else.

Comment: Don't do this without a `virtualenv` you will damage the default python!

Comment: BTW the last version of Python 2.7 is 2.7.18. Just substitute it in the code above.

Answer (score 3):

Here is new upgraded third party repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-2.7
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python2.7
python --version
```

Comment: `Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-2.7/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden`

Answer (score 2):

You can go to the python.org and download the .tar.gz file compile and install it.
You will need the basic tools in order to compile the source code.  I don't remember if the "build-essential" package will suffice but give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

The version you want is already in Ubuntu, in Vivid (pre)release. If you are brave, you can mix releases and install Vivid's version of Python under Trusty. Below is a generic solution that works on some packages, I can't warranty it with Python. The chances are ~ 50/50 that it will succeed. If you however find a proper *backports* repository for 14.04 with your required package version, then it should be a better choice.

1. You have '... trusty main' line in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, copy it twice, changing 'trusty' to 'utopic' and 'vivid'.
2. Run `apt-get update` and then `apt-get -t vivid install python2.7`. Review dependencies installed before proceeding. Abort upgrade when you suspect any damage to your system (deleted important packages, etc.).
3. Remove or hash the two lines from `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

**Never do it on production machines.** Make a backup of your OS and prepare boot media to restore it if needed. Expect problems on upgrades. You've been warned.